# Is there a simpler way to write a Clickhouse sql to avoid Decimal overflow?

Tags: sql, decimal, clickhouse

When I write a clickhouse sql exp, it always produce a decimal overflow exception, at last I have to write an exp like this...

```
SUM(b_cost])=0 ? toDecimal64(0,5) : toDecimal64(abs(SUM(a_cost)),5)/ (SUM(b_cost)=0? toDecimal64(1,5):toDecimal64(SUM(b_cost),5))- 1
```

Is there any way to simplify it? Both a_cost and b_cost are of type Decimal(32,20).

Comment: Could you provide the query that is producing the decimal overflow?